# STI where children include parent records (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

BACKGROUND: I have City model and I'd like users to be able to select both a Hometown and a Current City from the master list of Cities, so as to be able to call user.hometown and user.currentcities as methods.

QUESTION: What are some approaches for best tackling this scenario?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that City is itself a type of Community (there are other types of communities users can select besides City) - which is why I'm using STI.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to add `hometown_id` and `currentcity_id` as columns on the `users` table and then give the `User` model two associations:

```
belongs_to :hometown, :class_name => 'City'
belongs_to :currentcity, :class_name => 'City'
```

I don't think you need STI here unless I missed something.

**Edit**

If `City` is a sub-class via STI then changing `class_name` in the examples above to be the class of the base STI class should allow the `User` associations to link to a community.

Comment: I forgot to mention that City is itself a type of Community (there are other types of communities users can select besides City) - which is why I'm using STI. This is a good starting point for me though!